# Saving to a variable from async function Angular 5

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5, angularfire2

Hello I am new to angular and firebase and have been looking online but none of the solutions worked for me, hopefully someone can help. (if i'm not using to right terminology, I can clarify if you ask, like i said i'm new to this.) thanks.

I am trying to save data into a variable from within an async function. When I try to subscribe to it I get this error:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
        ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
        at EmployeeListComponent.ngOnInit (employee-list.component.ts:17)
```

What should happen:

1. save the data from angularfire store save it to a variable called employees: `Observable<Employee>;`

   > ```
   >  constructor(public afStore: AngularFirestore, private authService:
   >  AuthService) {
   >
   >              this.authService.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
   >                  this.employeeList = this.afStore.collection<Employee>('restaurantUsers/' + user.uid +
   >  '/employees');
   >                  return this.employees = this.employeeList.valueChanges();
   >              });
   >            }
   > ```
2. Return the data from a method called `getData()`

   > ```
   > getData(): Observable<Employee[]> {
   >         return this.employees;
   >       }
   > ```
3. Access it from component employee-listcomponent

   > ```
   >     export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
   >       constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService, private authService: AuthService) {
   >
   >        }
   >
   >       ngOnInit() {
   >         this.employeeService.getData().subscribe(data => {
   >           console.log(data);
   >         });
   >       }
   > ```

from my employee-listComponent -

```
@Injectable()
    export class EmployeeService {
      employeeList: AngularFirestoreCollection<Employee>;
      employees: Observable<Employee[]>;
      selectedEmployee: Observable<Employee[]>;



    constructor(public afStore: AngularFirestore, private authService: AuthService) {

        this.authService.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            this.employeeList =`enter code here` this.afStore.collection<Employee>('restaurantUsers/' + user.uid + '/employees');
            return this.employees = this.employeeList.valueChanges();
        });
      }


      getData(): Observable<Employee[]> {
        return this.employees;
      }



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService, private authService: AuthService) {

       }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.employeeService.getData().subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }

        **/////////////////////////////////////////////
        ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
        at EmployeeListComponent.ngOnInit (employee-list.component.ts:17)**
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `this.employees` is `undefined` in `EmployeeService` until your asynchronous request completes. You'll need to initialize it to a stream and push the records onto that when they come back from the server. The simplest way would be to use a `Subject` and set it to replay the last value for any late subscribers.

Depending on what you are really trying to accomplish here, there may be a better way to solve your problem than holding onto those records.

Comment: I have been doing some research based on what you said, and I think i'm going to attempt to use flatMap() to pass the data along. Hopefully I can figure it out, I will post here once i do.